# Unable to refresh JSON data in RecycyclerView Using SwipeRefreshLayout in Android

Tags: android, json

Android XML Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Android Activty Java Code

```
public class Sample extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL_DATA = "http://uat.ziplife.in/mobileapp/home_post_service.php";

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private List<Data_SAerver> data_sAervers;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
loadRecyclerViewData();
            }


        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(
                android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linaralayout1);

        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Sample.this, Posts_DATA.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        data_sAervers = new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();

    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA,

                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        String filename = "";
                        String filetype = "";

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray posts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
                            if (posts != null && posts.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject fileObj = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String fName = fileObj.getString("firstname");
                                    String created_at = fileObj.getString("created_at");
                                    String post_desc = fileObj.getString("post_desc");


                                    Log.e("Details", fName + "" + created_at + "" + post_desc);

                                    JSONArray files = fileObj.getJSONArray("files");
                                    if (files != null && files.length() > 0) {
                                        for (int j = 0; j < files.length(); j++) {
                                            JSONObject Jsonfilename = files.getJSONObject(j);
                                            filename = Jsonfilename.getString("file_name");
                                            filetype = Jsonfilename.getString("file_type");

                                            if (filetype.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                                                filename = "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/convert/" + filename;
                                            } else if(filetype.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                                            {
                                                filename = "http://uat.ziplife.in/img/Post/compress/" + filename;
                                            }

                                            Log.e("Files", "" + filename);
                                        }
                                    } else

                                    {
                                        filename = "";
                                        filetype = "";
                                    }

                                    Data_SAerver item = new Data_SAerver(fName, created_at, post_desc, filename, filetype
                                    );
                                    data_sAervers.add(item);
                                }

                             //  swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            }

                            adapter = new MyAdapter(data_sAervers, getApplicationContext());

                            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

I am unable to refresh JSON data in recyclerView using SwipeRefreshLayout. When I pull down it's rolling but nothing will happen new data not fetch.
What's the error in my code?

Comment: Please add your json data here. That will help us to find out the solution more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(data_sAervers,Sample.this); 
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Comment: you missing this line ,  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();